# Is it dangerous to display a parameter from URL without escaping?

Tags: html, spring, jsp, security, web

Say I'm in a Spring environment and I have an URL http://www.example.com/name=alice

In the controller, I have code like,

```
mav.addObject("name", request.getParameter("name"));
```

And in the JSP file, it is rendered like

```
<div><c:out value="${name}" /></div>
```

My question is,

1. If a malicious user appends a bad string, for example, a short script in the URL, like `http://www.example.com/name={some bad script}`, `<c:out>` will protect me, is my understanding correct?
2. What if I cannot use `<c:out>`? Say, the parameter is "alice&bob", `<c:out>` will turn it to "alice%26bob", which is not what I want. How can I protect myself in this case?

Comment: Use input - as from the URL - is dangerous if it is *ever* used in a context where it is not properly escaped (or parameterized). The value returned from `getParameter` is already URI-*unescaped* so it might be "alice<script>doMeanStuff()</script>bob".

Comment: But the above is not strictly related to what I expect the 'real question' is of: How can one safely show *literal text* in HTML from data - of *any* source - which contains special XML/HTML characters, such as ampersands or angle brackets? What about in contexts where c:out is not available/applicable?

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to escape and sanitize untrusted input before you send it to the client.
Coding it by hand is painful and error prone. But you could use [SafeHtmlBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlBuilder.html) for example. :-)